# Unable to run the program

Tags: processing

I am making a game in Eclipse Mars using the Processing library. I had made the game elsewhere and it ran fine. There were no errors after I copied and pasted the files from my flash drive to the folder in Eclipse. When I tried to run it, it said "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches." There were no recent launches because I had just gotten Eclipse. My code is as follows:

```
Main Class:

    //package dogeball;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;
import java.awt.Color;
import processing.core.PFont;

public class Dogeball extends PApplet {
    Ball ball;
    Furniture butterChair;
    Furniture[] bricks;
    PFont dogefont;
    float py;
    float score;
    boolean game;
    int checker; 
    boolean mode;

    PImage img = loadImage("doge.jpg");
    PImage img2 = loadImage("doge2.png");
    public void setup() {
        checker = 0;
        size(300,250);
        game = false;
        mode = true;
        ball = new  Ball(this, 100, 225, 0, 0, 10, Color.DARK_GRAY );
        butterChair = new Furniture(this, 130, 238, 40, 10, Color.YELLOW);
        py = butterChair.w /2;
        bricks = new Furniture[56];
        dogefont = loadFont("ComicSansMS-48.vlw");
        for(int rowNum = 0; rowNum<8; rowNum+= 1) {

            for(int colNum = 0; colNum<7; colNum += 1){

                bricks[7*rowNum + colNum] = new Furniture(this, 10+40*colNum, 10+15*rowNum, 40, 15, Color.red);
                score = 0;
            }
            }


    }
    public void draw() {



        if(game == false) {
        background(img);
        fill(0,255,255);
        textSize(30);
        textFont(dogefont);
        text("DogeBall",33, 170);
        fill(255,255,0);
        textSize(20);
        text("Press Space", 120,190);
        fill(255,0,0);
        text("Such BrickBreaker", 20, 20);
        fill(0,0,255);
        text("Much Atari", 190, 80);
        fill(0,255,0);
        text("How Breakout", 150, 230);
        }
        if(keyPressed == true) {
            if (key == ' ') {
                game = true;
            }
        }

        if(game == true) {
            if(keyPressed == true) {
                if (key == 'm') {
                    mode = !mode;
                }
            }
            //checker = 0;
            background(img);
            ball.appear();
            ball.hover();
            butterChair.appear();
            if(mode == true) {
            butterChair.x = mouseX-butterChair.w/2;
            }
            if(mode == false) {
            if(keyPressed == true) {
                if (key == CODED) {
                    if (keyCode == LEFT){
                        butterChair.x -= 3;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(keyPressed == true) {
                if (key == CODED) {
                    if (keyCode == RIGHT){
                        butterChair.x += 3;
                    }
                }
            }
            }
            if(butterChair.x <= 0) {
                butterChair.x = 0;
            }
            if(butterChair.x >= width - butterChair.w) {
            butterChair.x = width - butterChair.w;  
            }
            textFont(dogefont);
            fill(255,0,255);
            text("Much Doge", 12, 160);

            fill(255,0,0);
            textSize(20);
            text("M to toggle mouse mode.", 20,200);

            fill(0);
            textSize(10);
            text("You might have to press twice", 10,220);

            fill(0,0,255);
            textSize(20);
            text("Press S to Start", 150, 230);

            if (keyPressed == true) {
                if (key == 's' || key == 'S'){
                    ball.vy = 2;
                    ball.vx = 1;
                }
            }

            /*if(mousePressed == true) {
                ball.vx = 0;
                ball.vy = 0;
            }*/

            for(int i = 0; i<56; i+= 1) {
                bricks[i].appear();
            }


        }

        detectCollision();

        if(ball.y >= height) {
            checker = 0;
            if(checker ==0){
            background(img);
            ball.vx = 0;
            ball.vy = 0;
            textSize(30);
            fill(255,0,0);
            game = false;
            text("Such Sorry", 130, 160);

            fill(0,255,255);
            text("Much Game Over", 20, 215);

            fill(255,255,0);
            text("So Losing", 10, 30);

            textSize(20);
            text("Press P to Play Again", 20, 245);
            }
            if(keyPressed == true) {
                if(key == 'p') {
                    game = true;
                    ball.x = 100;
                    ball.y = 225;
                    checker = 1;

                    for(int rowNum = 0; rowNum<8; rowNum+= 1) {

                        for(int colNum = 0; colNum<7; colNum += 1){

                            bricks[7*rowNum + colNum] = new Furniture(this, 10+40*colNum, 10+15*rowNum, 40, 15, Color.red);
                            score = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }   





    }



    void detectCollision() {


        if(keyPressed == true) {
            if(key == '-')
                     {
                for(int cCode = 0; cCode < 56; cCode += 1) {
                    Furniture b = bricks[cCode];
                    b.x = width * 2;
                    b.y = height * 2;
                    score = 56;
                }
            }}



        if(ball.x >= butterChair.x &&
                ball.x <= butterChair.x + butterChair.w &&
                ball.y + ball.s /2 > butterChair.y) {
            ball.vy *= -1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<bricks.length; i+= 1) {
            Furniture b = bricks[i];
            if(ball.x >= b.x && ball.x <= b.x+b.w && ball.y-ball.s/2 <= b.y) {
                b.y = height * 2;
                b.x = width * 2;
                ball.vy *= -1;
                score += 1;
            }
            if(score == 56){
                background(img);
                ball.vx = 0;
                ball.vy = 0;
                fill(255,0,0);
                textSize(20);
                text("Such Winning!", 20, 20);
                textSize(40);
                fill(0,255,0);
                text("Much Congrats!",12 ,160);
                textSize(20);

                fill(255,0,255);
                text("Press P to Play Again", 20, 245);

                if(keyPressed == true) {
                    if(key == 'p') {
                        game = true;
                        ball.x = 100;
                        ball.y = 225;
                        checker = 1;

                        for(int rowNum = 0; rowNum<8; rowNum+= 1) {

                            for(int colNum = 0; colNum<7; colNum += 1){

                                bricks[7*rowNum + colNum] = new Furniture(this, 10+40*colNum, 10+15*rowNum, 40, 15, Color.red);
                                score = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    static public void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main("Dogeball");
    }

}

Ball Class:

    //package dogeball;

import java.awt.Color;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Ball extends PApplet {
    float x;
    float y;
    float vx;
    float vy;
    float s;
    Color c;
    PApplet p;

Ball(PApplet pApp, float xLocation, float yLocation, float xSpeed, float ySpeed, float size, Color shade){
    x = xLocation;
    y = yLocation;
    vx = xSpeed;
    vy = ySpeed;
    s = size;
    c = shade;
    p = pApp;
    }

    void hover() {
        x += vx;
        y += vy;

        if(x< 0 || x> p.width) {
            vx *= -1;
        }

        if(y< 0) {
            vy *= -1;
        }
    }
    void appear() {
        p.fill(c.getRGB() );
        p.ellipse(x,y,s,s);
    }


}

Paddle Class:

    //package dogeball;

import java.awt.Color;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Furniture extends PApplet {
float x;
float y;
float w;
float h;
Color c;
PApplet p;

Furniture(PApplet PApp, float locationX, float locationY, float fWidth, float fHeight, Color shade) {
    x = locationX;
    y = locationY;
    w = fWidth;
    h = fHeight;
    c = shade;
    p = PApp;
}

void appear() {
    p.fill(c.getRGB());
    p.rect(x,y,w,h);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have probably the wrong project selected on the projects tree or the run configurations are set to another project, since you haven't run it yet.

Either way, you have to **right click** your projects folder on the projects tree, then find **Run As > Java Applet**.

---

Another way to do it would be adding a `main` function, as you already did, and run is as a **Java Application**. Instead of using the current main function, you can try to use the code below to see it in present mode and see if it works:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "Dogeball" });
}
```

Comment: I tried right clicking the project and running it as a java applet but it said "Selection does not contain an applet."

Comment: Update: I did that and now it says the following in the console and does not run the program.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Dogeball (wrong name: DogeBall)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10133)
 at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:9967)
 at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:9949)
 at DogeBall.main(DogeBall.java:257)

Comment: @brsgaming804 Sorry. Instead of "Dogeball" try "DogeBall", with a capital B.